# After upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10 Openshot shows distorted video when clip in timeline

Tags: video, 15.10, editing

Openshot displays the video correctly in the box when I click on the title after importing it. However, when I drag the clip onto the timeline and start editing the image seems to go into negative/multi coloured but distorted display (there must be a name for the effect but sorry I do not know it!). SMplayer is displaying video correctly so it appears to be a problem when editing video. Has anyone any idea what's going on please?

Comment: Happens to me too. It is a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/openshot/+bug/1489922

Comment: Thank you Cornelius. I followed the link and tried to install the PPA without success, I think it may be outdated. Thanks again for trying. Bernie W